# PHP get_browser() function Output error

Tags: php, browser, get

I tried to use the get_browser() function in php and here is the code:

```
<?php
    $browser=get_browser(null,true);
    echo $browser['browser'];
?>
```

It just prints out default browser.
Please help

I have alredy modified php.ini file to detect browscap.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best at php and still learning myself, However you could try this...

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Or you could just have...

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Let me know how you get on.. Thanks.